# No sé dónde se referencia ret antes de la asignación

Tags: python

Este es el código, tengo que determinar cual es el producto más barato en un diccionario cuyas llaves son los nombres y sus valores son los precios:

```
def producto_mas_barato(catalogo: dict)->str:
    """ El novio tacaño
    Parámetros:
      catalogo (dict): Diccionario que contiene los nombres de los productos como llaves y sus respectivos
                       precios como valores.
    retorno:
      str: El nombre del artículo más barato en el catálogo. Si no hay ningún artículo que valga menos de
           10000, rornará None. Si el catálogo está vacío, rornará la cadena "No hay productos para
           escoger".
    """
    if len(catalogo) != 0:
        k = list(catalogo.keys())
        v = list(catalogo.values())
        if min(v) < 10000:
            m = 0
            rep = 0
            for m in range(0, len(v)):
                if v[m] == min(v):
                    rep += 1
                m += 1
            if rep == 2:
              i = 0
              for i in range(0, len(v)):
                  if v[i] == min(v):
                      prod1 = k[i]
                      if len(prod1) != 0:
                          prod2 = k[i]
                  i += 1
              if prod1[0] > prod2[0]:
                r = str(prod2)
              elif prod1[0] == prod2[0]:
                l = 1
                if prod1 > prod2:
                  while l < len(prod2):
                    if prod1[l] > prod2[l]:
                      r = str(prod2)
                    l += 1
                else:
                  while l < len(prod1):
                    if prod1[l] > prod2[l]:
                      r = str(prod2)
                    l += 1
              else:
                r = str(prod1)
            else:
              j = 0
              while j < len(v):
                if v[j] == min(v):
                  r = str(k[j])
                j += 1
        elif min(v) > 10000:
          r = None
    else:
      r = "No hay productos para escoger"
    return r
    pass
```

Y el error que me sale es este: UnboundLocalError: local variable 'r' referenced before assignment, no entiendo donde referencio a r antes de la asignación (el problema me aparece indicado en el return por alguna extraña razón).

Comment: La estás devolviendo en el `return`, pero puede ser que en el bloque `if` no reciba ninguna asignación si no se da el caso correcto. Puedes definirla con un valor inicial justo antes del `if`.

Answer (score 0):

No logro replicar el problema para decirte donde está el error, pero no importa, ya que la principal cuestión es que el código es muy complicado para algo que debe ser sencillo. Ver: [Zen de Python](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zen_de_Python)

Ya que se vale usar `min()`, entonces más corto el asunto: (1) calculas el valor mínimo, (2) ubicas el índice de ese valor mínimo, (3) extraes el key que corresponde al indice del valor mínimo y lo retornas.

```py
def producto_mas_barato(catalogo: dict)->str:
    if not catalogo:
        return "No hay productos para escoger"
    k = list(catalogo.keys())
    v = list(catalogo.values())
    min_val = min(v) # El valor minimo
    min_val_pos = v.index(min_val) # La posición del valor minimo
    return k[min_val_pos] if min_val < 10000 else None
```

Comment: Tampoco yo veo la relación entre el código del OP y lo que supuestamente desea hacer.